# Undefined parameter Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to define the parameter firstname from the prompt but it shows that it's undefined and goes at the end of the template string.

```
'use strict';
const yearsret = (year, firstname) => {
    const age = 2022 - year;
    const retir = 60 - age;
    return `${firstname} retires in ${retir} years`;
}

console.log(yearsret(prompt('Please enter your birth year')), (prompt('Please enter your Name')));
```

and the result

```
undefined retires in 27 years Ali
```

Comment: It's a typo. And closing as such. Follow your parentheses and you'll spot the issue.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you meant to put `years` not `days` in your return sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typo. Your parenthesis `()` is in the incorrect spot. Try this:

```js
console.log(yearsret(prompt('Please enter your birth year'), (prompt('Please enter your Name'))));
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but, we can close questions for *typo* reason.